# Get rid of navigation symbols but remaining left right arrows

Tags: beamer, navigation

I were annoyed by the buttons since I got nothing by clicking on them. But the little arrows besides them can navigate for me. The problem is that the arrows always invisible in the footline's black bg. Does there any way to highlight the arrows while hide the button? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[17pt]{ctexbeamer}  

\usetheme{Warsaw}  
\usecolortheme{whale}  
\makeatletter  
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}  
{%  
%\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!25!white}  
\leavevmode%  
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%   
\ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%  
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%  
  \else%  
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%  
  \fi%  
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%  
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%  
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.65\paperwidth,ht=.3\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%  
 \vbox to.3\@tempdimb{%  
       \vfill ~\color{white!75!black}\insertinstitute%~\(\cdot\)~\inserttitle
        \vfill%  
      }%
\end{beamercolorbox}%  
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.35\paperwidth,ht=.3\@tempdimb,center]{section in head/foot}%  
 \vbox to.3\@tempdimb{%  
\usebeamercolor[black]{navigation symbols}%  
\vfill\insertframenavigationsymbol\hfill%  
~\color{yellow!75!black}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\ %  
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\color{white!75!black}\insertshortdate~{}%  
\vfill%  
}%  
\end{beamercolorbox}%  
  \fi%  
}  
\makeatother  

\title{高等数学}\subtittle{无穷级数}\author{Author}
\institute[short]{long}\date{\today}  

\begin{document}  

\frame{\titlepage}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post code to reproduce your problem as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reduce the navigation symbols to only the slide navigation by setting another beamer template and change the color by changing `navigation symbols dimmed`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*%
  {navigation symbols}%
  {reduced}%
  {\hbox{\insertslidenavigationsymbol}}

\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works well except the middle button still stand some space.